# Alphanumeric search in RadCombobox wpf

Tags: wpf, telerik, wpf-controls, alphanumeric, radcombobox

I have this

```
         <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="Radcombobox1"
                IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ExpUserControl, Path=EXPSearchHeaderBL.ExpItems, Mode=OneWay}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=ExpUserControl, Path=EXPSearchHeaderBL.SelectedExpItem, Mode=OneWay}"
                TextSearch.TextPath="MetaId"
                TextSearchMode="StartsWith">
                    <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                    <CheckBox.Content>
                                        <TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} / {1}">
                                                    <Binding Path="Name" />
                                                    <Binding Path="MetaId" TargetNullValue="N/A" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </TextBlock.Text>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </CheckBox.Content>
                                </CheckBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Now am able to search with MetaId do am I able to search with both Name and MetaId ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think alpha numeric search is not possible